# How do I compare file's signature to a database of signatures?

Tags: java

I have a database stored in memory of different files headers. I would like to test the signature of a given file for example a .jpg  to those signatures in the database.

Consider that scenario, the signature of the file to be tested is FFD8FFE0, but in the database, there is only a partially matched signature of FFD8FF, and some times, the database has also a signature of FFD8, but to a different type but to the same file format. 
How do I correctly retrieve the correct matched signature of the tested file ?

I wrote the following function but it doesn't work in all file formats.

```
 public static boolean searchSignature(File file, List<FileSignature> db) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_SIGNATURE_SIZE];
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int n = in.read(buffer, 0, MAX_SIGNATURE_SIZE);
        String hex  = toHex(buffer);
        boolean b = true;

        // for each signature in the database, compare it with file's siganture
        for (FileSignature fs : db) {
             if (!fs.getSignature().contains(hex)) {
                b = false;

            }
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Short remark: you should `close()` your input stream!

Comment: Also, you use `contains()`: it will match anywhere in the string. Are you sure you didn't mean `startsWith()`, ie `hex.startsWith(fs.getSignature())`?

Comment: @fge
Thanks for the remark. I tried startsWith, but it didn't work.
For example: Consider the file's signature is FFD8FFE000104A46
The database has a signature of FF D8 FF only, it should be matched, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be

```
if ( hex.startsWith( fs.getSignature() )
```

Since hex is longer than the signature from your DB.

If you have both FFD8FF and FFD8 you can't differentiate between the longer and shorter signature.

Comment: What if fs.getSignature() Returns a signature of "FF" for a "Windows executable" file, but the actual signature of the file is FFD8FFE00, and it is related to JPEG file, using the above condition, will be true, however both signature are not matched.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Than your approach won't work, and you could try to have separate collections of signatures for executables,images,video audio and documents 'detected' by their file names extension.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Also returning a boolean doesn't work, you could try to find the longest matching signature. In this case FFD8FE00 would prefered over FF